# Calculating rotation delta between two quaternions (as another quaterion)

Tags: math, quaternions

I have some initial rotation `r0` represented by quaternion and some actual rotation `r` (also an quaternion). I would like to get the quaternion that represents the delta of rotation.

E.g. if `r0` stands for `30st OX` rotation and `r` is `50st OX`, the `rDelta` should contain quaternion that represents `20st OX` rotation.

**How to compute the `rDelta`?**

My guess is either:

```
rDelta = r0.getConjugated() * r
```

or

```
rDelta = r.getConjugated() * r0
```

? But maybe none of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you want to find `rx` where `rx * r0 == r1`?

```
rx * r0 * conj(r0) == r1 * conj(r0)
rx == r1 * conj(r0)
```

All you need to know is that a rotation around `q = q2 * q1` is equivalent to a rotation first around `q1` and then `q2`. If you want to go from an initial rotation `r0` to the final rotation `r1` you simply substitute: `r1 = rx * r0` where `rx` is the missing step between `r0` and `r1`.

Comment: I guess that's the correct answer. I understand the transformations. But how did you made the first statement from my description (`rx * r0 == r1`)? I mean, how to read it?

Answer (score 0):

Your quaternion `q(R2/R1)` represent the rotation of R2 w.r.t. R1

Your quaternion `q(R3/R1)` represent the rotation of R3 w.r.t. R1

You wish to have the rotation of R3 w.r.t. R2

That is `q(R3/R2) = q(R3/R1) * q(R1/R2) = q(R3/R1) * conjugate(q(R2/R1))` where * is the product of quaternion

Answer (score 0):

It depends , how your rDelta will be applied (from right or left)

1 )r = r0 * rDelta; r = r0 * conj(r0) * r; rDelta == conj(r0) * r;

2 )r = rDelta * r0; r = r * conj(r0) * r0; rDelta == r * conj(r0);

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but if I remember correctly, assuming you're in Unity and applying Q's in Right-to-Left order (because it's left-handed?), then in order to get "from" Q1 "to" Q2, you first inverse Q1, then apply Q2 to the result of that, and that gives you the delta. How much you need to rotate from Q1, to get to Q2..

```
    Quaternion r0 = Quaternion.Euler(10, 0, 0);
    Quaternion r = Quaternion.Euler(20, 0, 0);
    Quaternion rDelta = r * Quaternion.Inverse(r0);
```

Heck, I don't even know what a quaternion conjugate is! I think for homogenous matrices, they're the same as the inverse? Yep, just looked that up.

This is answered here too: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/143430/relative-quaternion-rotation-delta-rotation-produces-unstable-results